# Stumped on Exercise 5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to learn Python.  Been at this one for hours.

What I am trying to do is to enter a few numbers (for example 7, 4, 6, 10, & 2) and then print the maximum and minimum.
 My code works perfectly for every number I enter that is 1-9. Once I hit 10 or higher it goes wonky.
It appears that it is reading 10 as a 1 with a zero attached to it and it says 10 is the minimum.
Where am I going wrong here?
.
The exercise is to enter a few numbers and then print the maximum and minimum. My code works perfectly for every number I enter that is 1-9. Once I hit 10 or higher it goes wonky and lists 10 as the minimum.
  Where am I going wrong here?
.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
the_list = []

while True:
    num = input('Enter a number or done: ')

    #Handle the edge cases
    if num == 'done' : break
    if len(num) < 1 : break # Check for empty line

    # Do the work
    try :
        number = int(num)
        the_list.append(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        #continue

print(the_list) # NOTE: This is new so I can see what is in the_list

for value in the_list:
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = value
    elif value < smallest:
        smallest = value

for the_num in the_list:
    if largest is None:
        largest = value
    elif the_num > largest:
        largest = value #the_num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print( "Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: the `min` and `max` functions exist for a reason, btw :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for responding Adam.  I will keep that in mind for different situations.  The assignment required more than I shared so in this case I couldn't do it that simply.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't append `number` to the list but you append `num` to the list (a simple typo, I presume). Thus, you never append an `int` to the list but the `str`. Obviously, this will create problems later when you compare strings, such as:

```
>>> '10' < '3'
True
```

Change `the_list.append(num)` to `the_list.append(number)`

---

Another error is that in your second `for` loop you forgot to change `value` to `the_num`

Comment: Note that this still won't make the code right, since he's iterating with `the_num` but comparing and adjusting `value` when he's finding the largest number

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  Changing to "the_list.append(number)" and "value" back to "the_num" did the trick.  I saw peter's response first.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are appending the string to the list, not the integer. That is, your list consists of the following right now (if you entered 2 and then 10:

`the_list = ['2', '10']`

Since strings are compared lexicographically, '10' is less than '2', because '1' is less than '2'. What you want to do is to append the integer.

```
try :
    number = int(num)
    the_list.append(number)
except:
    print("Invalid input")
    #continue
```

This way, you'll be comparing the numerical values of the numbers, and you'll get the correct answer!

Comment: This did the trick Peter.  Thank you so much.  I suspected that I might be adding the number entries as a string but wasn't certain how to check for that.  That was going to be my next area to research.